# php function that takes a number and subtracts 1% 3 times

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, foreach, php-7

I'm trying to create a php method that will take an int and subtract `1% 3 times`. So for example if we passed in a number like `100`. It would then remove `1% looping 3x`. So something like this:

```
input = 100

return
-> 97
-> 94.09
-> 91.2673
```

Comment: And what you have tried so for?

Comment: `subtract 1% 3 times` then how's your output starts from 97?

Comment: calculate as you like then use number_format, ceil, round, floor or whatever you like to do.There is no function such as plus(1, 1) because simply you can output 1 + 1

Comment: Either  https://eval.in/606403  OR  https://eval.in/606402

Comment: I think @Anant captured so precisely what op  meant check out: https://eval.in/606403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i get from your out put is:-

3% of the first input and then 3% of the new number(comes from the first calculation)and then again 3% of the new number (comes from the second calcultion). So you have to do it like below:-

```
<?php

$original_input = 100;
$new_one = '';
for($i =1;$i<=3;$i++){
   if($new_one !==''){
     $new_one = $new_one - ($new_one*3/100);
   }else{
     $new_one = $original_input - ($original_input*3/100);
   }
  echo $new_one.'<br/>';
}
```

***Output:-*** https://eval.in/606403

***First what i think is captured here:***-

https://eval.in/606402

Comment: @kevinabraham  glad to elp you, but next time you have to put your efforts too.

Comment: I made a mistake and forgot to post what I had done so far. The answers came so quick I didn't have time to update. But no excuses next time I will not make the same mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a simple for loop

```
<?php

echo "enter number";
$temp = fopen("php://stdin","r");
$line = fgets($temp);

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
$tpc=($line*3/100);
$line=$line-$tpc;
echo " $line \n";
}

?>
```

Sample output:

```
enter number100
97 
94.09 
91.2673
```